# Render multiple svg in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have many `svg` files that I need to add to HTML but still have the opportunity to change the color by class(all at once). I want to render them from JavaScript Array with urls or pathes somehow, but not sure what ti use, as `<img>` tag doesn't have all the `svg` functions I need. Saw a solutions with `<img>` and `filter`, but would be great to have a more convenient one.

It would be best to find pure Java Script solution

Comment: You could try to use an svg tag directly in the html and add class attributes to the svg elements.

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I'm asking about
I need first to add those svg tags but not manually

Comment: @keyc9 then take what ozoid said and make a single default svg element on the page that you copy however many times you need and change the source as you need with JS

Comment: Take inspiration from the Native JavaScript [``<load-file>`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) I blogged about.